# R: fixed x axis scaling and converting plot() xy arguments to points()

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, points, segments

I have a data.frame `xy` which I am plotting like in the code below.

Is there a way how I could convert my `xx` and `yy` in the  xy plot() to a `points()` command so that I could set `type='n'` and add `points()` after the segments commands in order to control it better?

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),ID=c(87,87,87,199,199,199), X_START_YEAR=c(1984,1986,1984,1899,1909,1924),Y_START_VALUE=c(75,25,-90,-8,-55,-10),X_END_YEAR=c(1986,1994,1999,1909,1924,1927), Y_END_VALUE=c(20,50,-15,-70,-80,-100))
xy
  NAME  ID X_START_YEAR Y_START_VALUE X_END_YEAR Y_END_VALUE
1 NAME1  87         1984            75       1986          20
2 NAME1  87         1986            25       1994          50
3 NAME1  87         1984           -90       1999         -15
4 NAME2 199         1899            -8       1909         -70
5 NAME2 199         1909           -55       1924         -80
6 NAME2 199         1924           -10       1927        -100   

ind <- split(xy,xy$ID)

for (x in ind){
  xx = unlist(x[,grep('X_',colnames(x))])
  yy = unlist(x[,grep('Y_',colnames(x))])    
    fname <- paste0(x[1, 'ID'], '.png')
    png(fname, width=1679, height=1165, res=150)
    par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
    plot(xx, 
         yy,
         main=unique(x[,1]),
         xlab="Time [Years]",
         ylab="Value [m]")
    axis(1, at = seq(1000, 2050, 5), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3)
    axis(2, at = seq(-100000, 100000, 500), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3)
    x <- x[,-1]
    segments(x[,2],x[,3],x[,4],x[,5],lwd=2)
    dev.off()
  }
```

If it is possible it would be great if the x axis could be at a fixed range (e.g. from 1940 to 2014) and if values before 1940 are present the x axis should be automatic. The range of the y-axis always differs. How could I incorporate that in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME = c("NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME1", "NAME2", "NAME2", "NAME2"),
                 ID = c(87, 87, 87, 199, 199, 199), 
                 X_START_YEAR = c(1984, 1986, 1984, 1899, 1909, 1924),
                 Y_START_VALUE = c(75, 25, -90, -8, -55, -10),
                 X_END_YEAR = c(1986, 1994, 1999, 1909, 1924, 1927), 
                 Y_END_VALUE = c(20, 50, -15, -70, -80, -100))
xy

ind <- split(xy, xy$ID)

for (i in ind){

  xx = unlist(i[, grep('X_', colnames(i))])

  yy = unlist(i[, grep('Y_', colnames(i))])    

  fname <- paste0(i[1, 'ID'], '.png')

  png(fname, width = 1679, height = 1165, res = 150)

  # test for xx smaller than 1940
  if(any(xx < 1940)) {

    my_x_lim <- c(min(xx), max(xx))

  } else {

    my_x_lim <- c(1940, 2014)}

  # plot the data using pch at your choice and color them as you like
  # plot your x limits
  par(mar = c(6, 8, 6, 5))

  plot(xx, 
       yy,
       main = unique(i[, 1]),
       xlab = "Time [Years]",
       ylab = "Value [m]",
       pch = 21, col = "black",
       xlim = my_x_lim)

  axis(2, at = seq(-100000, 100000, 500), cex.axis = 1, labels = FALSE, tcl = -0.3)

  i <- i[, -1]

  segments(i[, 2], i[, 3], i[, 4], i[, 5],lwd = 2)

  points(xx, yy, pch = 21, col = "black")

  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! This is doing what I want, perfect! One little detail I am having problems with and maybe you have a solution for it: I'd like to plot the points with `pch=21` and `bg='white'` which results in a white round point with a black margin. However now the plotting of the points is called first and then the segments are drawn over the points. This doesn't look as good as when the white points with a black margin are plotted over the line segments. This is why I was looking for a solution with `points()` initially so that I could define the order of the features to plot...

Comment: thank you!! Didn't see that it was so easy to incorporate. You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The ggplot2 library has a segment facility, which makes plotting such data extremely compact, and thus both easy to maintain and adapt for future reference. Here it is.

It's essentially seven lines, but could be further compacted. Note the additional inspiration for modifying the x-axis.

```
dat = xy

# Adapted from the other solution
if(any(dat$X_START_YEAR < 1940)) {  
  my_x_lim <- c(min(dat$X_START_YEAR), max(dat$X_END_YEAR))
  } else {
    my_x_lim <- c(1940, 2014)
  }

# plot based on Hadley Wickham's ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(dat)
p = p + geom_segment(aes(x = X_START_YEAR, xend = X_END_YEAR, y = Y_START_VALUE, yend = Y_END_VALUE))
# p = p + facet_wrap(~ID)
# proposal to uncomment if y-axis should not be equivalent over multiple facets (makes the plot harder to read, though):
p = p + facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free")
# Alternatively, only let the x-axis scale vary freely (this gets you ride of the initial procedure to determine the x-axis limits)
# p = p + facet_wrap(~ID, scales = "free_x")
p = p + xlab("Time [Years]") + ylab("Value [m]")
p = p + xlim(my_x_lim)
print(p)
```

[image]